# Use typename keyword behind the template declaration

Tags: c++, templates

When I read the [source code](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/eigen-2.0.1/src/eigen3/Eigen/src/Eigen2Support/MathFunctions.h), there are something really confuse me

```
template<typename T> inline typename NumTraits<T>::Real ei_real(const T& x) { return numext::real(x); }
template<typename T> inline typename NumTraits<T>::Real ei_imag(const T& x) { return numext::imag(x); }
template<typename T> inline T ei_conj(const T& x) { return numext::conj(x); }
```

and then I read something else in  the c++ source code

```
template<typename _Tp>
inline typename
__gnu_cxx::__enable_if<__is_byte<_Tp>::__value, void>::__type
__fill_a(_Tp* __first, _Tp* __last, const _Tp& __c)
{
  const _Tp __tmp = __c;
  __builtin_memset(__first, static_cast<unsigned char>(__tmp),
           __last - __first);
}
```

this function use memset to initialze the vector

Now there is 2 questions:
1. why use typename like this `typename NumTraits<T>::` what does it mean?
2. explain the `typename __gnu_cxx::__enable_if<__is_byte<_Tp>::__value, void>::__type`, it's too long to hard to understand.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: I even don't know how to express my question，: (

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords